# Rename tag java-util-scanner to java.util.scanner

Tags: discussion, tags

Should the tag [java-util-scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-util-scanner) should be renamed to `java.util.scanner` to conform to the formatting of all the other `java.util.*` tags on Stack Overflow?

Examples:

[java.util.concurrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.concurrent)

[java.util.logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.logging)

[java.util.date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.date)

[java.util.calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.calendar)

[java.util.stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not! [Done.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.scanner) (If the linked page appears empty it may take a minute or so for the changes to propagate.)

Comment: That was quick! Cool.

Comment: I happened to spot your question mere seconds after it was asked. Web sockets are a godsend.